# Two Shrinkwrap modifiers to one Shape Key

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Hey guys, I have two shrinkwrap modifiers that successfully shrink my object 1 onto object 2 without any artifacts, and now I want to apply them to a single shapekey. However I have found that it seems impossible to apply and save the two shrinkwraps together at the same time... any ideas？

Answer (score 4):

**This part is only about merging shape keys, but I'll just leave it here. The solution is the Edit below.** You can create two single shape keys, one for each *Shrinkwrap* modifier as you already found out.

Now go to the *Object Data Properties* and there under *Shape Keys* you should find them both. Set both values to 1, so that they both fully affect the mesh (or set them to any values where you like the result).

Now click on the *Shape Key Specials* menu (the arrow pointing downwards, below the +/- buttons) and choose *New Shape from Mix*. This creates a new shape key with the combination of the others as result for value 1. You can now delete the original shape keys.

**//EDIT:** So I thought you had converted both *Shrinkwrap* modifiers into shape keys and wished them to be one. I never needed two shrinkwraps on one object so I didn't test that and focused on merging the shape keys.

It turns out, that when I apply the first *Shrinkwrap* as shape key, at first of course its effect is gone (because the shape key is set to value 0), but if you set it to 1, the shape key and the second *Shrinkwrap* should produce the same result as before (at least in my test they did).

If you now apply the second *Shrinkwrap* modifier as shape key, you can delete the first shape key and only keep the second - because this one has already merged the influence of the first one into it. So remove the first shape key and if you then set the value to 1 on the second, it should show the result of both *Shrinkwrap* modifiers. If not, I would ask you to load your file so that we can check with your specific model.

[image: shape key mix]

Comment: It doesn't work for me ... by applying one by one modifier I didn't get the same result https://imgur.com/u24zhXY ... but I could miss something here :)

Comment: My problem is, I have no idea how to quickly construct objects which make two _Shrinkwrap_ modifiers necessary so I first of all went on from the premise I could convert both two shape keys. Now I've tested it and can make a small edit to my answer.

Comment: If you want to find out the issue - [blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5lznGLxB/) ... I would say by applying only one modifier you loose relationship of vertices of second modifier based on stack ...

Comment: @vklidu Works as expected, described in my edit. The merging of shape keys is not necessary, after creating the second you can delete the first one.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can ...

- duplicate object (delete modifiers if any)
- select also original (with Shift it became **Active**) and
- under *Shapekeys* > **Join as Shapes**

[image]

Alternatively you can add **Boolean** modifier to one of the **Target** object, than you can use only one *Shrinkwrap* modifier and use *Apply as Shapekey*

Blend contains both ways ...
[image]

Comment: Why not make two shape keys and simply join them into one?